# jQuery form selector doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put a generic form submit function.
For some reason the form submit action is not being captured at all by jQuery.
I am using the following:

```
$('form').submit(function( event ) {
    alert("Form submit through ajax");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I never get the alert and the form goes for a normal post submission which invariably fails as the back-end is a python django class based view that is specifically handling the ajax requests. I am new to jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup(
        {type:'POST'});
    $('.nav_menu').click(function(){
        var hostname = window.location.origin;
        alert("hostname = " + hostname + $(this).attr("id"));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: hostname + $(this).attr("id"),
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
                            var page = data['page'];
                            $('#view_area').empty();
                            $('#view_area').append(page);
                    }
        });
    });

    /*$('form').submit(function(){
            alert("Form submit in ajax");
            //$(this).ajaxSubmit();
            return false;
    });*/
    $('form').submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault(); // <-- important
        alert("Form submit through ajax");

        /*$(this).ajaxSubmit({
                target: '#output'
        });*/
    });
    $(':submit').click(function(){
        alert(":submit = Form submit through AJax");
    });
});
```

That is the full jQuery file.
The following is my html from where the form is present.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>D.O.B</th>
            <th>Marital Status</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Alt Mobile</th>
            <th>Alt Contact</th>
            <th>Office Number</th>
            <th>Primary Address</th>
            <th>Permanent Address</th>
            <th>Secondary Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for e in entry_all %}
            <tr><th><form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                        <label for="id_emp_id"></label> <input id="id_emp_id" maxlength="50" name="emp_id" type="hidden" value="{{ e.emp_id }}" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Remove">
                    </form>
                </th>
                <th>{{ e.emp_id }}</th>
                <td>{{ e.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.dob }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.marital_stat }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.cell_no }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.cell2_no }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.alt_no }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.off_ll }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.prim_addr }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.perm_addr }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.sec_addr }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: did you try wrap it in document.ready??

Comment: what error is shown in the browser console(press <kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: If you're using Firebug you can debug your code and evaluating new expressions to see what is happening. You can do with other browsers also.

Comment: If you are new, you should read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Is it a dynamically generated form ?

Comment: Where's the AJAX part?

Comment: Its being served from a different js file. The other items are working

Comment: This issue cropped up after reading the jqerry and trying out the ajax stuff. My jquerry 'form' selector should promptly give an alert for any and all form submits. I dont know why the selector is not picking up the form submit events. I added 3 selectors to test them out. None of the alerts crop up. The 'nav_menu' item works. But I am using a class to define them. Why cant I get it to select all forms in general.

Comment: I have not added the ajax part yet. I just wanted to test the form handler first to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally using a cdn to load a jquery. For some reason this is not working all the time for me. So I decided to serve it statically. Strangely, cdn links have no issue on my team mates system. No code change.

Answer (score -1):

*EDITED*

Code below should work as expected.

In jQuery, there's a preventDefault method which you can call to prevent the default action of an event. For forms, the default action is to either "GET" or "POST" data to or from the script or page provided in the form's action parameter.

If you want to prevent the default action of your form (stop it from submitting and following the action url), you need to call preventDefault <s>first and foremost</s> somewhere in your handler code.

Here's an example:

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Now I can run...");
    // do AJAX call
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "your-script.py",
        data : { foo : "bar" }
    })
    .done(function(results) {
        // done with post
        // parse data returned from Python
        // available in results parameter
    });
});
```

If your handler is *not running at all*, you're likely not referencing your form correctly.

Comment: I do not know the reason of the problem but do not think it is the answer. Here you can check the documentation of preventDefault function http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: The OP doesn't even see an `alert`, so presumably the event handler is not even executed, and moving `event.preventDefault()` to the top of the handler won't change that. *" if you want to prevent the default action of your form [...], you need to call preventDefault first and foremost in your code."* That's not true, you can call `event.preventDefault()` *anywhere* in the event handler to prevent the default action.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that `preventDefault()` doesn't need to be called first and foremost. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I can get it to work with a id selector but I am trying to write a generic handler for all the forms in the project so that all forms are routed to ajax back-end. So I need to be able to select the 'form' objects in general. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: using `$("form")` as your selector is still valid. It does not make a difference.